# SQL - Find top rows where parameter is the same

Tags: postgresql

I am learning sql and I am jumping into more complicated queries. I have the following tables:

players:
Columns: name, school_name, gender

simple:
Columns: player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, category, tournament_number, score

My entries in the simple table will be similar to this. Each line is the score by a player at a specific tournament number.

```
Joe, Harvard, Junior, 1, 40
Joe, Harvard, Junior, 2, 30
Joe, Harvard, Junior, 3, 60
Anne, MIT, Senior, 1, 45
Anne, MIT, Senior, 2, 55
Anne, MIT, Senior, 3, 20 etc.
```

What I am looking to do is to get, for each player, the sum of his / hers top two scores of the season:

Joe, Harvard, 100
Anne, MIT, 90

I have the following query:

```
SELECT player_name_fkey,
       school_name_fkey,
       sum(t1.score) AS sum_scores
FROM (
  SELECT player_name_fkey,
         school_name_fkey,
         score,
         rank() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS scorerank
  FROM simple
    LEFT JOIN players ON players.name = simple.player_name_fkey
  WHERE category = 'Benjamin'
    AND gender = 'Masculin'
  GROUP BY simple.player_name_fkey,
           simple.school_name_fkey,
           simple.score
) t1
WHERE scorerank <= 2
GROUP BY player_name_fkey,
         school_name_fkey
```

Unfortunately, this query returns only the top 2 scores over all players. How can I change it to get what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the rank *per player*. You are currently calculating the overall rank.

To do it per player, you need to add a `partition by` to your window function:

```
rank() over (PARTITION BY player_name_fkey order by score desc) AS scorerank
```

You also need to remove the `group by` from the inner (`t1`) query:

```
SELECT player_name_fkey,
       school_name_fkey,
       sum(t1.score) AS sum_scores
FROM (
  SELECT player_name_fkey,
         school_name_fkey,
         score,
         rank() over (PARTITION BY player_name_fkey order by score desc) AS scorerank
  FROM simple
    LEFT JOIN players ON players.name = simple.player_name_fkey
  WHERE category = 'Benjamin'
    AND gender = 'Masculin'
) t1
WHERE scorerank <= 2
GROUP BY player_name_fkey,
         school_name_fkey
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think there was a typo on your answer (rrank instead of rank). Thank you again!